# How can I allow Select permissions to a single record in a column?

Tags: sql, select, permissions

The goal is to allow all the "Teachers" that have access to the Faculty table to have Select permissions to only their own social security number and not everybody elses. Do any of you know how I can perform something like this? I do have all my users setup as Windows Users and I have a windows group called Teachers, if that helps.

Comment: Use a view, "select ... where ssid = ssid(current_user)", grant access to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible using the standard permissions in SQL server (that I am aware of)

You will need to implement this kind of constraint in your code.

You could in theory pass in the SS# and query based on this and raise an error if they do not match.

Answer (score 0):

Social security numbers shoud be encrypted so they can't see each others numbers if they call up the record.  You can use a decryption proc to allow them to decrypt that checks the userid against the profile id and will only decrypt if they match.

Comment: I think this will be the best option, if I create a decryption proc. I'm going to find out how to do this and get back to everybody. Thanks a lot HLGEM.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing Row-level Permissions
Row-level permissions are used for applications that store information in a single table. Each row has a column that defines a differentiating parameter, such as a user name, label or other identifier. You then create parameterized stored procedures, passing in the appropriate value. Users can see only rows that match the supplied value.
The following steps describe how to configure row-level permissions based on a user or login name.
Create the table, adding an additional column to store the name.
Create a view that has a WHERE clause based on the user name column. This will restrict the rows returned to those with the specified value. Use one of the built-in functions to specify a database user or login name. This eliminates the need to create different views for different users.
    ' Returns the login identification name of the user.
    WHERE UserName = SUSER_SNAME()

```
' USER_NAME or CURRENT_USER Return the database user name.
WHERE UserName = CURRENT_USER()
```

Create stored procedures to select, insert, update, and delete data based on the view, not the base tables. The view provides a filter that restricts the rows returned or modified.
For stored procedures that insert data, capture the user name using the same function specified in the WHERE clause of the view and insert that value into the UserName column.
Deny all permissions on the tables and views to the public role. Users will not be able to inherit permissions from other database roles, because the WHERE clause is based on user or login names, not on roles.
Grant EXECUTE on the stored procedures to database roles. Users can only access data through the stored procedures provided.